# Trouble with Intersect on a variable-named range in a For loop

Tags: excel, vba

Trouble with Intersect of the activecell selection with a variable-named range within a loop. The logic is if there's an intersect in the two ranges, set "RR" range to equal the variable-named range. Here's the relevant code. Assume I dimensioned all variable names correctly:

```
Set R1 = Range("B2:AB4")
Set R2 = Range("B5:AB7")
Set R3 = Range("B8:AB10")
.
.
.
Set R9 = Range("B26:AB28")

Set AC = Selection

For i = 1 To 9
    If Not Intersect(AC, Range("R" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Set RR = Range("R" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Next step isn't necessary to include with above as I do the exact same with defined column ranges (C1, C2, C3....C9) and save the identified intersect column variable as "CC" -same basic loop. Lastly, I need to select the intersect of the RR and CC ranges for later steps.

I'm sure this is a simple syntax mistake or a fundamental misunderstanding of Excel objects, but I'm stuck. Help?

Comment: You may be looping through  cells R1 to R9, not named range R1 R9. May try collection of ranges or loop through  each area of a union of ranges

Answer (score 0):

You should use a collection. That will allow you to access your custom ranges:

```
Sub test()

    Dim col As New Collection

    Set R1 = Range("B2:AB4")   'OR   col.add Range("B2:AB4"), R1
    Set R2 = Range("B5:AB7")   'OR   col.add Range("B5:AB7"), R2
    Set R3 = Range("B8:AB10")  'OR   col.add Range("B8:AB10"), R3
    '.
    '.
    '.
    Set R9 = Range("B26:AB28") 'OR   col.add Range("B26:AB28"), R9


    col.Add R1, "R1"
    col.Add R2, "R2"
    col.Add R3, "R3"
    col.Add R4, "R4"
    col.Add R5, "R5"
    col.Add R6, "R6"
    col.Add R7, "R7"
    col.Add R8, "R8"
    col.Add R9, "R9"


    Set AC = Selection

    For i = 1 To 9
        If Not Intersect(AC, col("R" & i)) Is Nothing Then
            Set RR = col("R" & i)
        End If
    Next i

    Set col = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think is more appropriate  to use Exit for in the if branch.

Comment: No, @AhmedAU please read the OP again. No where is it mentioned that he/she would like to exit for. The OP is simply trying to get code to work. My example accomplishes that as you cannot access R1 or Rn indirectly like the OP would like without a collection.  I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: I will try this first thing at work tomorrow morning and reply.  Thank you both for such swift help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative can be to use one range (255 characters limit) and access the individual [`.Areas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas) :

```
Set Ranges = Range("B2:AB4,B5:AB7,B8:AB10, ... ,B26:AB28")

For Each area in Ranges.Areas
    If Not Intersect(Selection, area) Is Nothing Then
        Set RR = area
    End If
Next i
```